# Erro ao mandar um parametro int atraves de uma intent

Tags: android

Pessoal estou fazendo um app que recebe um código do usuário e ele é em hexadecimal. Faço a conversão dele para decimal e insiro num shared preference. Até aí tudo bem.

Na hora que ele vai mandar o parametro para a outra activity dá erro:

> 03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testegerador/com.example.testegerador.Telagerador}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xa
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:230)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:265)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at com.example.testegerador.Telagerador.onCreate(Telagerador.java:28)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>   03-18 17:59:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(1983):     ... 11 more

E sai da aplicação.

A parte do código que dá erro é esta, pois quando deixo isto como comentário o app roda normalmente:

```
@Override
public void onResume () { //Verifica se o usuário é licenciado ou não
 super.onResume(); 

    //teste para ver se o sharedpreference codfinal nao esta nulo mas esta vazio ("")
    int teste = cod_final.getInt("codfinal",0);

    //verificacao de primeiro launcher
    //  if (sPreferences.getBoolean("firstRun", true)) {

    //verificacao se o usuario digitou o codigo final se ele estiver null suponhamos que ele ainda nao validou a licenca pois nao digitou o codigo fornecido na ligacao
    if(cod_final==null || teste==0){


     //mensagem de não licenciado           
      final ProgressDialog ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Você não está licenciado!", "Processando sua licença ...", true);
      ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
      new Thread(new Runnable() {   
       @Override
       public void run() {
        try {
         Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          }
        ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }           
       }).start();


      //captura o IMEI do dispositivo           
      TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
      String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId().toString();
      licenca.setText(IMEI);


       //marca como false o sharedpreference: quer dizer que usuario esta licenciado
      //sPreferences.edit().putBoolean("firstRun", false).apply();

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "codigo final NULO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } /*Fim if(cod_final==null || teste==""){*/

    else{/*se houver codigo final quer dizer que o usuario esta licenciado
           entao abre a tela para gerar os codigos enviando o parametro que é o numero do cod_final
           que aparecera para o usuario como licencas restantes*/                    
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "codigo final NAO nulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //pega o conteudo da sharedpreference e converte para string
               int licencas_resto = cod_final.getInt("codfinal",0);


               //aqui mostra o que realmente está no sharedpreference que no caso é um valor int , 
               //que é o valor hex digitado pelo usuario convertido em decimal. 
               //Isso está numa outra parte do código, não coloquei aqui porque está funcionando normalmente. 
               Log.i("CODIGO FINAL", "o que esta inserido em cod final" + licencas_resto); 

               //abre tela de geração de códigos
                Intent X = new Intent("tela_geralicencas");//chama a tela de geracao de codigo
                X.addCategory("gerar");
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putInt("mensagem",licencas_resto);
                //params.putString("mensagem", licencas_resto);
                X.putExtras(params);
                startActivity(X);
            }/*Fim else*/
  }/*Fim   public void onResume () {*/`
```

Código da outra Activity:

```
package com.example.testegerador;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Telagerador extends Activity {

  TextView tvResto;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_telagerador);

      tvResto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);

      //Recebe o parametro da outra tela que no caso e o numero do cod final
      Intent intent = getIntent();
      Bundle params = intent.getExtras();   
      if(params!=null)
      {   
       //converte o valor recebido pelo parametro em string   
        int mostraTexto = params.getInt("mensagem");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mostraTexto, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       //insere no textView o valor de licenças restantes
        tvResto.setText(mostraTexto);
      }/*Fim if(params!=null)*/

  }/*Fim OnCreate*/

}/*Fim  public class Telagerador extends Activity {*/
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Os tipos estão certos não sei o que acontece.

Só lembrando sou iniciante nessa área. Desde já, obrigada!

Comment: Uma sugestão para encontrar o erro seria criar um *breakpoint* no início do método, e ao chamar o método, ir passando linha por linha para descobrir qual linha gera a *`FATAL EXCEPTION`*.

Comment: o breakpoint seria o debug?

Comment: *Breakpoint* seria a instrução que o programa vai parar para que você analise. Quando o programa atinge o *breakpoint*, a IDE vai mostrar os dados existentes na classe ANTES da execução daquela instrução. Então você pode saber exatamente qual instrução faz a *`FATAL EXCEPTION`*.

Comment: Coloca o código do seu onCreate() da classe Telagerador.java.  E a princípio você está usando, em um Toast, um resource String que não existe.

Comment: Coloquei Luidne. Vou tentar mutlei.

Comment: @mutlei eu coloquei os breakpoints e rodou toda a parte da chamada de tela. Antes de passar pelas chaves que fecham o else e o OnResume o debug vai para uns arquivos estranhos e para no arquivo ThreadGroup.java especificamente na linha `if (parent != null) {`. E ai dá o erro no logcat.

Comment: Quando ele chega na linha `if (parent != null)`, qual o valor do parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que você esteja errando quando tenta passar os valores.
Verifique o código abaixo.

**Enviar código da licença**

```
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Telagerador.class) // Acredito que Telagerador seja a tela que você deseja receber valores...
            .putExtra("licencas", licencas_resto);
```

**Receber código da licença**

```
    int mostrarTexto = getIntent().getIntExtra("licencas", -1);
    tvResto.setText(String.valueOf(mostrarTexto));
```

Veja se funciona. Eu analisei o seu código, e a única coisa que *eu* vi incorreta foi o modo como você chamou a `Activity`, pois eu não encontrei nenhuma classe com o nome `tela_geralicencas`.

Mas se isto não resolve seu problema, deixe um comentário que irei *refazer* a resposta afim de lhe dar uma ***solução***.

Comment: Deu certo! Muito obrigado @array!

Comment: Não é nada, @Kaamis! =]

Comment: Me desculpe pelos erros no código, eu fiz no bloco de notas. haha!

Comment: Magina, ajudou bastante!